# Averaging property dropping the $L^1$ condition

Tags: real-analysis

Now I have encountered the averaging property, and I want to figure out if it still hold when dropping the condition of $L^1$.

Here is the statement.

Assume $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, $\forall x\in [0,1]  \ $and$\ \delta>0$,$\exists$ interval $\ [a,b]\subset[0,1],s.t.\ x\in[a,b]$, $b-a<\delta$, and $\int_{[a,b]}f(x)dx\geq0$ (Note that here we do not assume $f\in L^1[a,b]$), can we draw the conclusion that $m\{x\in[0,1]\mid f(x)<0\}=0$?, here $m$ denotes the standard Lebesgue measure.

All suggestions are welcomed! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CalvinKhor $\int_a^{b}f(x)dx$ may be  $\infty$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I mean that maybe on some intervals, $\int_{[a,b]}f(x)dx$ does not converge, it escapes to infinity.

Comment: How are you defining $\int_{[a,b]} f(x) dx$ for such a function who takes values in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Please notice that $\forall x\ \in \ [0,1]$, there exists an interval.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Separating the fuction into its positive part and its negative part and if the  integral of them do not escape to infinity at the same time, the integral can be defined.